# Overriding page width for div

Tags: css, html, width, overriding

My page is set up so all elements are contained in a 640px page-width (mobile site), as such:

```
html, body {
    width: 640px;
    padding: 25px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

All elements are have the same margin on both sides with a padding of 25px.
This works, but I have an element that I'd like to have spanning the whole width of the page, so overruling the fact that all elements must be centered in a width of 640px.

Probably I am taking this the hard way, and maybe I should change other things on my page to better make all elements align in that 640px width. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this quite a few times in my life with full-width headers and background images, and I've found the cleanest solution is to section off parent elements according to what they are in the doc(`header`, `content`, etc.), keep them full width, and wrap their content-containing children in a container. For instance:

```
<header>
    <div class='headerWrap'>
        <!-- some content -->
    </div>
</header>

<section class='backgroundImage'>
</section>

<section class='content'>
    <div class='contentWrap'>
        <!-- some content -->
    </div>
</section>
```

Then set the styles as such:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    background: #00cae9;
}

.headerWrap {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.backgroundImage {
    background: url('images/myimage');
    /* other styles */
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    background: #f9f9f9;
}

.contentWrap {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```